# Select and deselect row after another selection - ReactJS Hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html-table, row

Have a list of licenses plates that start with a disabled button and no line selected.

Here is what should to do:

1. When select a row, button "Go foward" enable;
2. When select a row already selected, deselect it and disabled button again.
3. When list have a row selected and user click in another row, deselect old row and select the new one.

The snippet code i did:

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galileo-mw3p3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Facing this problems:

1. Need 2 clicks to set css style 'custom-col-row-active' to row selected. Button is enable already first click.
2. When a line is already selected, when you click on the other lines, they are selected as well. With 1 click on a selected line, all are deselected.

I know need use data table to deselect line already select, but i don't know how to get the full data table, since i only get the data when i click in a specif row.

Any tips here?

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael, I don't know much about tabler-react, but this is just my suggestion for you. Your `handleSetActivedRow` seems to have problem. I don't understand why you have written `onClick={(e) => handleSetActivedRow(e)}`. You are calling a function inline when onClick itself and again you are taking it to an other function `handleSetActivedRow`. This is bad coding; instead you can do like this `onClick={handleSetActiveRow}`. secondly, you need to check again your handleSetActiveRow function. I don't understand why you want to return? when it is not necessary. What you need to check on is that you want to set the className to -active when you click on an element.

Comment: i'm newbie using react. Thanks for the tips! @Bhushan Nayak

Comment: @Rafael, you have to split your code into separate components, like your data should be separate, rows should be separate.. you can have a clear understanding when you separate components and it will not be confusing and you can pinpoint the problem. You can separate your data like this --  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {... -- take it out into a separate file and insert like so.. const data = [ { license_plate: your data }]; export default data; Then u import the data into ur App.js and use it. Also, there is no id in your data & ur calling row._id which is not existing.

Comment: You separate your renderRow into a separate component and i'll help you solve your problem. Get back if you are still working on your project.

Comment: I'll try to solve this in next days or week, for now, put it in stand by to implement other features. Thanks for help @Bhushan Nayak.

Comment: I think i'm almost there. https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galileo-mw3p3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/DataTable.js

Comment: As i will use this component for all list pages, header and row should be dinamic. Put RenderRow inside DataTable, is it ok?

Comment: Currently problem is: without the setters of `handleSetActivedRow` function, row selection works like a charm. It bugs when setting the data returned by clicked row and enable button `Go Foward` in a state. I think it's happen because setting hook in `handleSetActivedRow` trigger before` getRowDataOnClick`.